# Strange thing on tomcat "ps old gen" memory

Tags: jvm, tomcat7, heap-memory

It happend something strange.

I have a server ubuntu 8.04 LTS Jvm 1.6.0.24

Everything run ok in test mode.

When i release the server to the users (i use mod_jk to redirect input from apache), it runs well for a while and then in few seconds the PS OLD GEN memory (1.3 GB) fills up and make tomcat unresponsive.

I checked memory leaks and thread leaks in the application, but everything seems ok.

Has some one experienced something similar ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you check for memory leaks?

Comment: hi, i check them by tomcat7 manager memory leaks detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat [MemoryLeakProtection](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) doesn't detect every possible memory leak.

I recommend you to actively check for a memory leak getting a JVM heap dump when problem appears and analyzing it.

There is plenty of information in SO to help you with the task

- [How to find a Java Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119/how-to-find-a-java-memory-leak)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716597/java-memory-leak-detection-tools
- [How to find memory leaks using visualvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154785/how-to-find-memory-leaks-using-visualvm)