# How to find memory used by the java class?

Tags: memory, heap-memory

I'm using ubuntu 14.04. IS there any way to find how much heap is used by the java class or process?

When I run **top** command, %CPU and %MEM denotes what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `top` gives you the CPU and memory usage of a single Java virtual machine. Concurrency in Java programs is usually achieved using threads, i.e. you have many threads inside a single Java virtual machine. To get more information about the memory usage of a particular thread or other component of a Java program, you have to look inside the virtual machine, for example by capturing a heap dump and analyzing it using [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/). MAT and other tools are also explained in [How do I analyze a .hprof file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185893/how-do-i-analyze-a-hprof-file). Another possibility should be attaching [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io) to the Java virtual machine but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jvisualvm that is included in the JDK.

```
 $YOUR_JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisualvm.
```

In the profiler, you can choose either CPU or Memory profiling that should 
show you what you want.

You can find some documentation here : https://visualvm.java.net/profiler.html