# Jmeter issue while running more threads with more load

Tags: jmeter

I have jmeter Thread.  In thread I have 20 samples.
i need to test 300 users per 15 minutes test for 24 hour.

I am facing Pthread failure error.

I tried looping. But it is running in just 1 or 2 hours
Could some one help?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noMVI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your have not specified the error. I would like to suggest increase the heap of jmeter.

```
Procedure to increase heap size in JMeter:
1. Go to the bin folder of JMeter apache-jmeter-<version> -> bin
2. Right-click and open jmeter.bat file in notepad or notepad++
3. Search for the keyword ‘set Heap’
4. You can see the default heap size (1 GB – may vary in your JMeter version)
5. set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
6. Change the -Xms (initial heap size) and -Xmx (maximum heap size) values. You can increase these values up to 80% of total heap. In my case, I just increased the max heap size value. Refer to the below arguments:
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

**OR** a better option is running the test in distributed mode when you are running a long test.
Refer [this.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your test to run 24 hours set Loop Count in the Thread Group to `Infinite` and "Duration" to `86400000`

[image]

If your test ends prematurely check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), it should contain the reason, if the reason is not there - check for any [.hprof files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185893/how-do-i-analyze-a-hprof-file) in JMeter's working directory

With regards to your test plan overall design: are you aware that all your [Pre-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) which are visible at the screenshot will be executed **before each sampler** and whether it is something you really want to do? Most probably you should move them to be children of specific Samplers, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) for more details.