# Apache Jmeter crashing and close in the middle of the run from CMD

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

When i run the script with small number of users/threads and via the CMD the run finishes smoothly (188) users

when i increased the users to 1000 with a ramp up of half an hour steady state for 1 hour and ramp down for half hour

the run crashed in the middle with a errorlevel=-1 ,
[error from the CMD when it crashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNhbB.png)
things i've done :
-Increased the Heap size to 18g as the machine has memory of 32g
-iteration time is 1 min
-think time 5 seconds

is there anything that can be edited in the jmeter configurations or this error is coming from the windows itself?

Comment: you should consider distributed testing. a standalone machine may lack resource to ramp up so many users.

Answer (score 0):

Your `errorlevel=-1` doesn't tell anything to us apart from the fact that JMeter Java process has exited with non-zero [exit status.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)

The reason most probably in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

You can also check the presence of [.hprof files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185893/how-do-i-analyze-a-hprof-file) in the folder where you launched JMeter from, if this is the case - it indicates that JMeter has encountered an [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html)

With regards to `edited in the jmeter configurations` - just make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and if you do already you should consider allocating another machine and running your test in [Distributed Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)